# should I use microsoft's portable library tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, portable-library-tools

I came across Microsoft's Portable Library Tools add-in for Visual Studio, but I see System.Xml.Linq is not in the supported list at this time (but does exist on my target platforms).

Knowing that I'm going to have to do some work myself to get multi-platform linq to xml support, does the PLT add-in do anything else for me?

Answer (score 0):

The goal for portable library tools is to have the minimun set of dependencies in order to allow you to create a cool library for different type of projects. The idea is to not to have dependencies in this kind of library, just Dto, Model and some similar stuff are good examples of use